# HTML elements following physics thanks to matter.js (and p5.js)

Tags: javascript, onclick, physics, p5.js, matter.js

I'm building a system using these languages where dom elements are created by clicking and behave with proper physics. Basically speaking, the elements are created in setup with visibility hidden, at click an array of boxes is created containing matter.js rectangles, each with each dom element's sizes. In draw, everything is then updated to that the dom elements have the position and the rotation of the matter.js elements. Hope i managed to explain everything properly lol.

this is the final results, where everything seems fine: https://codepen.io/giambrodo/pen/RwBvRjV

the issue is when trying to style everything and double-check the physics by using a canvas to visualize the matter.js rectangles this happens: https://codepen.io/giambrodo/pen/WNKjgmg

boom! what did i do wrong? I mean the DOM elements are clearly not aligned with the rectangles, especially for p elements where when they get styled they go crazy. I can't grasp my head around how that happened. Please. Someone help me :(

P.S. I've clearly seen this [HTML elements with Matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420347/html-elements-with-matter-js) and even if in a slightly different way it seems quite the same to me, but still, I have encountered those issues.

I've used this:

```
  img[this.id].position(this.pos.x - img[this.id].width/2, this.pos.y - img[this.id].height/2);
  img[this.id].style('transform', 'rotate(' + this.angle + 'rad)');
```

Comment: Why do you need a canvas if you're already using the DOM? Can you share a [mcve] in the question itself? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen i use the canvas just to check for the actual position of the matter.js rectangles through the p5.js ones, which are always aligned in my code. The issue it's right there; how do i make the dom elements to be aligned with the rectangles?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Links can go down or change over time, so the normal standard is that the code is in the question itself. Feel free to check my [MJS+p5.js answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6243352+%5Bmatter.js%5D+%5Bp5.js%5D) for examples. I usually don't click to other links, but seeing as how I'm more or less the only active MJS answerer, I took a quick look. Two potential problems: your canvas is offset from the page, so add `body {margin: 0}` to your CSS to fix that. Second, paragraphs are drawn from the center rather than top-left, so they're 50% off on both axes.

Comment: Changing `img[i].style('margin', '-0.5em');` below the `createP` gets it in the ballpark, so hopefully you can debug from there.

Comment: really thanks for your suggestions! I know what you mean, I'm new to StackOverflow and i wasn't sure about the best practices being not just a few lines of code. 
About what you suggested to me, I see, but why is the nonstyled paragraph seemingly positioned correctly, while as soon as i change its size, it's not anymore? 
For the canvas, you're right, I just didn't notice because I use it only to check for the rectangles' position

Comment: @ggorlen update if you're interested: yeah apparently tweaking values for the margin gets the job done, the issue is that that's not a good way to do that, as soon as i change the size of the p I'm back with the same problem. I really don't understand why my code doesn't make it work automatically. I will update it and add it to the question, as you asked me